# Bullet Physics - Step outside of body

Tags: c#, physics, bullet, physics-engine, bulletphysics

I have an interesting little problem using the Bullet Physics engine.

In the course of physics occurring, it's natural within this engine for a RigidBody to be as much as 0.01 units inside of another body. This is fine within the simulation, it knows to not fall through each other.

However, this is not good the moment you call `Body.Translate` to a recorded position. While a body entering another body naturally from the physics engine is fine, from a function call it is definitely not. By translating to a position that was the entity was previously in, the body no longer remembers to stay outside of that body, and simply falls through.

How do I go about any of the following:

- Stepping the moved Body outside any/all bodies it's touching.
- Preventing a Body from entering another
- Anything else that would keep the first Body from going through the second

(Note: my actual use case is a bit more complex than described, but this is essentially what's going on. I can provide more details if necessary).

Comment: Update: I'm not 100% set on bullet really... I'm playing with BEPU as well, and will accept an answer that uses BEPU instead of Bullet if it's easier there. (Though it looks like BEPU handles entities going inside other entities better from the start)

Comment: Yeah BEPU just straight refuses to fall through like Bullet does... might be switching engines if I don't get an answer here

Comment: Further update: it seems resetting the velocity to 0 every time helps encourage it to not fall through